# BusinessObjects: replace all not changing schema name in SAP BO universe

Tags: reporting, business-objects, universe

We are using SAP BO 3.1 R. We have one exciting universe and pointing the schema name of table to another database.

I tried using replace all option but it's not replacing schema name of one joining condition of table. When I am pulling columns in webi I can see old schema name with table name in where clause when it's joining two tables with sub query.

I am not sure where to find that joining condition in universe as universe is big. I tried with find option but not getting anything. I can see it in PDF format in joins list.

e.g. if it's `ABC.employee` I am trying to change it to `ABC_x.employee`.

Answer (score 0):

That does sound exciting.

Don't use find/replace.  Click-and-drag to select all the tables that need to change (or hit Ctrl-A to select all).  Right-click on one of the tables and click Rename Table.  Enter the new schema name in Owner, then click OK.

Comment: There are almost 100+ tables using different schemas I can't manually change them. Also I have changed owner name of all tables with replace all (changes looks good in properties of columns).Am facing problem with one joining condition given in universe as filter . When ever I pull one column it automatically apply filters and takes that joining condition in webi report.I want to find that joining condition (from where it's coming) to change that schema name.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Is the table that's referenced in the join actually in the universe?  It doesn't necessarily have to be, so it's worth checking.  BO *should* be able to find all instances of a table and update the owner correctly.